# How to put an enrich policy in elasticsearch when python package doesn't match documentation

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to place a simple enrich policy onto elasticsearch before its corresponding ingest pipelines. The issue I have is when I execute:

```
 if enrich_policies:
        for i, (name, body) in enumerate(enrich_policies.items()):
            result = es.enrich.get_policy(name=name)
            
            if "config" in body:
                body = body["config"]
        
            # cannot pass in "body", but the individual params 
            # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-enrich-policy-api.html#put-enrich-policy-api-request-body
            body_match = body.get("match")
            body_range = body.get("range")
            body_geo_match = body.get("geo_match")
            
            log_print(f"Putting policy {name} with match: {body_match}, range: {body_range}, geo_match: {body_geo_match}", "DEBUG")
        
            # upload enrich policy
            result = es.enrich.put_policy(name=name, match=body_match, range=body_range, geo_match=body_geo_match)
            
            # execute enrich policy
            result = es.enrich.execute_policy(name=name)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\source\xxx\configure_kibana_objects.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\source\xxx\configure_kibana_objects.py", line 116, in main
    result = es.enrich.put_policy(name=name, match=body_match, range=body_range, geo_match=body_geo_match)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\_sync\client\utils.py", line 414, in wrapped
    return api(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\_sync\client\enrich.py", line 188, in put_policy
    return self.perform_request(  # type: ignore[return-value]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\_sync\client\_base.py", line 389, in perform_request
    return self._client.perform_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\_sync\client\_base.py", line 320, in perform_request
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:11] [policy] unknown field [name]')
```

Elasticsearch version is 8.7.0

```
 python -m pip show elasticsearch
Version: 8.7.0
Summary: Python client for Elasticsearch
Home-page: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py
Author: Honza Král, Nick Lang
Author-email: honza.kral@gmail.com, nick@nicklang.com
License: Apache-2.0
Location: C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: elastic-transport
Required-by:
```

Here is the [link to the documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.7.0/api.html?highlight=enrich#elasticsearch.client.EnrichClient.put_policy) for the package, which includes the first parameter: `name`.

So why does the package keep yelling at me that there is no parameter `name`?

Answer (score 0):

There are three different types of the enrich policies available range, match or geo_match. You need to create one type of the policy and then call execute policy to create that enrich index.

```
body={
  "match": {
    "indices": "student_data_index",
    "match_field": "registration_id",
    "enrich_fields": [ 
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "date_of_birth",
            "father_name"
      ]
  }
}
client.enrich.put_policy(name="student_enrich_policy",body =body)
```

Execute enrich index

```
client.enrich.execute_policy(name="student_enrich_policy", wait_for_completion=True)
```